# Android: Autocomplete animation for CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, animation, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` from `Android Design Support Library` for animating toolbar in an activity. Problem is, that if i lift my finger in the middle of animation, toolbar doesn't continue with animating. It just stays half displayed on the screen. How can i fix it?

Here is a gif: http://goo.gl/GQGQqe

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are experiencing is, near as I understand, expected. However, there is a [`setExpanded()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean,%20boolean)) method which allows you to close/open the `AppBarLayout` programmatically, with the option of animating the process. As such, you may be able to listen for `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` events and launch an animation to open or close the it based on how far the `AppBar` has travelled from its original positions.

**Edit:** 
Here's an implementation I just tested on an emulator running KitKat:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //...
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (appBarLayout.getY() != 0) {
                //User has just finished interacting with the screen
                //and the AppBar is not fully expanded. So, to close 
                //it with an animation...
                appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit later, but just like explained in this post: [How to implement snapping in CollapsingToolbarLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563456/how-to-implement-snapping-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout) a new snapping feature was added. Just add 
  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
To your CollapsingToolbarLayout. Hope it helps.